# SPA with Backend API and new B2B API - how to deploy

Tags: api, deployment, architecture, strategy-pattern, b2b

I have currently delivered a SPA (Vue.js) web application with a Java API backend. Everything is currently sitting in AWS, with the frontend being in CloudFront and the backend in ECS connecting to a RDS instance.

As part of the next phase of delivery, we are creating a B2B API. My question is that of architectural design and deployment strategy, is it commonplace to just extend the existing API with B2B functionality? Should I keep them both separate with an API gateway in front? We envisage that the B2B use eventually will outgrow the SPA use case so the initial deployment configuration needs to have the most flexibility to grow and expand.

Is there some sort of best practice here? I imagine that a lot of code would be similar between the two backends as well.

Thanks,
Terry

Answer (score 1):

First off - Deciding on service boundaries is one of the most difficult problems in a service oriented architecture design and the answer strongly depends on your exact domain requirements.

Usually I would split service implementations by the domain/function as well as by organizational concerns (e.g. separate teams developing them) and not by their target audience. This usually avoids awkward situation where team responsibility is not clear, etc. If it will grow into a very large project there may also be a need for multiple layers of services and shared libraries - And at that point you would likely run into necessary re-factorings / restructurings.

So if there is a very large overlap in function between your b2b and the regular api you may not want to split the implementation.

However, you may also have to consider how the service access is provided and an API Gateway could help with providing different endpoints for the different audiences, different charging models, different auth options, etc. Depending on your exact requirements an API Gateway may not be enough and this may also require another thin service layer implementation that uses common domain services.